# Why does git store objects in directories with the first two characters of the hash?

Tags: git, directory-structure

I'm designing a directory structure based on UUIDs so I'm looking at what git does to see if it would be a good model.

I can see that git stores objects in a structure where the first two characters of the hash are used as a directory and the rest of the hash is the file name.

What I'm wondering is why? If there's a big advantage to using the directories why aren't more subdirectories created... say a directory for each one or two characters in the hash creating a tree? If there isn't a big advantage then why the directory with the first two chars?

Comment: Some file systems don't take very well to directories with tens of thousands of files. One layer of directories will mitigate that problem. A second layer would be overkill unless you have tens of millions of objects.

Comment: Since Git was initially implemented by Linus himself, one pretty much has to assume that a design decision like that would have been made as a tradeoff between breadth and depth in a way that was optimised for performance on Linux.

Comment: Interesting is there likely to be such limitations with the number of directories? In my structure each uuid is a directory.

Comment: @MonteGoulding Yeah, different filesystems have different limits on number of subdirectories as well as on number of files per directory. For instance, ext3 limits the number of subdirectories to 32k, while in ext4 it is unlimited.

Comment: @MonteGoulding I too was thinking of a similar design for object storage on the filesystem: <id>/{payload,metadata}, but, due to the subdirectory limitations, ended-up using: payload/<id>, metadata/<id>.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Git switches from "loose objects" (in files named like `01/23456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567`) to "packs" when the number of loose objects exceeds a magic constant (6700 by default but configurable, `gc.auto`).  Since SHA-1 values tend to be well-distributed it can approximate total loose objects by looking in a single directory.  If there are more than (6700 + 255) / 256 = 27 files in one of the object directories, it's time for a pack-file.

Thus, there's no need for additional fan-out (`01/23/4567...`): it's unlikely that you will get that many objects in one directory.  And in fact, greater fan-out would tend to make it harder to detect that it is time for an automatic packing, unless you set the threshold value higher (than 6700), because (27 + 255) / 256 is 1—so you'd want to count everything in `01/*/` instead of just `01/`.

One could use `0/1234567...` and allow up to ~419 objects per directory to get the same behavior, but linear directory scans (on any system that still uses those) are O(n<sup>2</sup>), and 27<sup>2</sup> is a mere 729, while 419<sup>2</sup> is 175561.  [Edit: that only applies to file creation, where you have a two stage search, once to find that it's OK to create and a second to find a slot or append.  Lookups are still O(n).]

Comment: But 256^2 is 65536...and that's the number of object directories.

Comment: Hmm... so this doesn't appear to match with @Thilo's reasoning for the file system limitations of a large number of files being why there's the directory structure unless someone changes the defaults a long way...

Comment: @nneonneo: In practice git gc's before there are 256 directories.  One un-gc'd .git dir I have here had 94, another has 105, a third has 65.  Also, I should note the n-squared behavior occurs on file create (the others are O(n)).

Comment: @torek Would you happen to have a source for your answer? This is very interesting and I can't find more info on this subject (design decisions for git/storing a lot of files)

Comment: @Yaurthek: I found a few comments in the git source code and possibly a few items scattered about on mailing lists.  Then did some arithmetic myself, and looked at various git repos I had.  The behavior of directories on "old" (non-Btree-directory) Unix-style file systems was well known from the days of Usenet storing every file in an N-digit numeric name.

Comment: If you wonder why `01` is 8 bits(2^8=256), follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529507/do-the-sha1-of-a-string-always-return-ascii-characters). In short, one sha-1 is actually 20bytes but printed as 40 bytes.