# What the name of directory in objects/ stand for?

Tags: git, subdirectory

I guess It is the fast way to access to specific file in git. But I don't know name of directory `06, 0d, 17, 27, 29, 2e` stand for what and why name for directory is `06` .

```
objects
   ├── 06
   │   └── d378aef5b28791df7c6b5a58c866d8569cac87
   ├── 0d
   │   └── 25470613db871791afd43ae724cbbe367c30ef
   ├── 17
   │   └── af6db51eca422ab8629a40cb54b8e5d8da2b3f
   ├── 27
   │   └── d749cd2a7e3d2b1e27080505e37b301f73108d
   ├── 29
   │   └── faabec2bc6b5a7b00a5d6d9ebc9f2a5daf3d5b
   ├── 2e
   │   └── e648b03e6b4bf45515a8eb3a3ab62400940fe2
```

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/18731887/1256452 as well (already answered though, so I will just put this in to link them)

Comment: Thank Torek for give me more knowledge, I’ve upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), when Git hashes an object, the output from the above is a 40-character checksum SHA-1 hash.  Git uses the first two characters from that hash as the name of the subdirectory, and the remaining 38 characters as the file name.

> If you again examine your objects directory, you can see that it now contains a file for that new content. This is how Git stores the content initially — as a single file per piece of content, named with the SHA-1 checksum of the content and its header. The subdirectory is named with the first 2 characters of the SHA-1, and the filename is the remaining 38 characters.

Comment: Splitting a big directory into smaller directories to keep the file system happy is somewhat confusingly also often called "hashing". Traversing a directory with a large number of entries is slow on many file systems, so it's better to have 100 directories with 100 files than one directory with 10,000 files.

Comment: @tripleee I was going to comment on this as well, but remained silent because I don't know precisely why Linus chose two characters rather then some other number.  We can also observe that having a folder system, with roughly 1000 max different folders, might also make it easier to navigate through the objects.